# Joining MySql tables with query value inside the fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have data on five tables I would like to pull.

Table 1 `users` has three Columns:

```
uid, username, data
```

Table 2 `users_order` has three Columns:

```
uid, orders_id, users_email
```

Table 3 `order_products` has three Columns:

```
orders_id, product_id, product_name
```

Table 4 users profile values has three Columns (below is the data in the row)

```
uid, fid, values
1     1   firstname
1     2   lastname
```

So, with Table 1 - 3 I was able to write the query like this

```
SELECT users.uid AS uid, users.username AS username, 
       users_order.orders_id AS orderId,     
       users_order.users_email AS userEmail, 
       order_products.product_name AS  productName 
WHERE users_order.uid = users.uid
AND users_order.orders_id = order_products.orders_id
AND order_products.product_id = 5 ;
```

Above query will give the results of

```
uid   usersname   orderId   usersEmail       productName 
1    xxusername   123       xxxuser@gmail    Product 1
```

I would like to bring in the Table 4 data Firstname and Last Name into query results.
So, the final query will be

```
uid    username    orderId     usersEmail    productName    FirstName    LastName
```

need help on query that added the Table 4 data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  u.uid AS uid, 
  u.username AS username, 
  o.orders_id AS orderId,     
  o.users_email AS userEmail, 
  p.product_name AS  productName,
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.fid = 1 THEN `values` END) AS 'First Name',
  MAX(CASE WHEN f.fid = 2 THEN `values` END) AS 'Last Name'
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_order o ON o.uid = u.uid
INNER JOIN order_products p ON o.orders_id = o.orders_id
INNER JOIN usersprofile f ON u.uid = f.uid
WHERE p.product_id = 5 
GROUP BY u.uid, u.username, o.orders_id, o.users_email, p.product_name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa064/1)

This will give you:

```
| UID |   USERNAME | ORDERID |     USEREMAIL | PRODUCTNAME | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | xxusername |     123 | xxxuser@gmail |   product 1 |        sam |       lin |
```

Assuming that each `values` entry in the user profile table has two `fid` values 1, 2 indicating the `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: Hi Mahmound,   The fid values show as values under the FirstName and Last Name . Not pulling the data

Comment: @samlim - Do you mean that, in the sample data you posted the `uid =1` has `firstname = 1` and `lastname = 2`?

Comment: @Mahmouned firstname and lastname are store in the table with three columns. fid , uid , value. In that table fid = 1 value is firstname, fid = 2 is last name.. So, fid = 1 ; value Sam and fid = 2 ; value Lim

Comment: @samlim - Thats what the query does. But I used `firstname` and `lastname` as a sample data instead of `sam` and `lim`. Try it.

Comment: Hi Mah, i try the query and First and Last name show up as values. not data pull

Comment: @samlim - Sorry, I just used `firstname` and `lastname` as a sample data. I updated my answer. See my edit. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Hi Mah,, i understand... under the header First and Last name. it show up just "values".. not coming up with Sam Lim

Comment: is there way i can AS the profile_values.fid = 1 AS firstName?

Comment: @samlim - Sorry I can't understand, it shows up sam in the firstname header, and lim in the lastname header. Do you want to show them in only one column? Can you please show me what is the desired output do you want for the samle data you posted. Thanks

Comment: the desired out put as you show it in the results but i not getting the Sam Lim under the column first name and Last name.. what is the "o" after the users_order and p after the order_products INNER JOIN users_order o ON o.uid = u.uid
INNER JOIN order_products p ON o.orders_id = o.orders_id
INNER JOIN usersprofile f ON u.uid = f.uid

Comment: did you plug in the data and tried? i try and all the columns able to pull the data from those field but firstname and lastname columns just show "values". i am just stuck

Comment: @samlim Are you sure you are using backquotes (not singlequotes) around values?

Comment: @samlim - Sorry again for confusion.